# Swift AVAudioplayer on Button press

Tags: iphone, swift, avaudioplayer

I am trying to have a button that will play a sound when pushed.

The app I have has 6 buttons (with 6 different sounds). I only have one listed because I am trying to get one button to work correctly before doing the rest. I know the button is working (from the print command at the bottom), but it is not playing the sound.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    var player : AVAudioPlayer?

    @IBAction func buttonOne(_ sender: Any) {
        func playSound() {
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "drinking", withExtension: "mp3")!

            do {
                player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                guard let player = player else { return }

                player.prepareToPlay()
                player.play()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.description)
            }
        }
        print("Anakin: IT IS WORKING!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you configured the AVAudioSession? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession

Comment: I did not. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is it printing any error?

Can you try doing this?

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "FILE NAME WITH EXTENSION", ofType:nil)!
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

do {
    let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    sound.play()
} catch {
    // couldn't load file :(
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! I tried to put that in instead of the "let url". Did not seem to work though :( . No error message, but no sound either (and I do have my volume on my laptop)